# argv remaining piece from last start

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to interact with our updater-software while it's runnung. Basicly asking for a status and beeing able to kill it remotly. To do so the program gets the host-ip and the command to do via the command line when I start it. Something like this:

```
./updater_killer <host_name> die
```

This itself works fine. But when I use a longer command and than do a second start with a shorter one, the rest of the first command fills up the second one:

```
./updater_killer <host_name> status
./updater_killer <host_name> die
```

the first one works fine. But for the second one I get the following message:

```
unknown command: dietus
```

I tried it with even longer commands with the rest of those remaining on the next start aswell.

This is the part where I use `argv[2]` to send the command after I established the connection.

```
if (send(sockfd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]), 0) == -1)
  perror("send");
```

I don't alter `argv[2]` in any way befor it's used. I allthough tried to store it in a `string` or `*char` befor sending it. But non of that helped. I assumed it's something about the memory and that it's still allocated. But I have no idea how to free `argv` befor the next start of the program.

What do I need to to, to get rid of the remaining piece from the last command on the next start of the program?

**EDIT:**

With the answer from EJP I fixed this on the side of the receiver:

```
if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
  perror("recv");
  exit(1);
}
buf[numbytes] = '\0';
```

With the `buf[numbytes] = '\0';` it now works. I'm not jet shure if I can rely on `numbytes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiver is clearly ignoring the length returned by `recv()`. However you're also assuming that one `send()` equals one `recv()`, which isn't true. You need to devise an application protocol, e.g. a length-word prefix, that tells the receiver how much data to expect in the message. This is *not* necessarily the same as the value returned by `recv()`.

Comment: I'm guessing the receiver is assuming the data read from the socket is a nul-terminated string.  Note that the `send()` code posted does *not* nul-terminate the data sent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If the receiver is assuming that, it should read until it gets the null, rather than proceeding as soon as one `recv()` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed it on the recivers side (and edited that into the question for others to see what I did) and that works fine. But I don't unterstand the `This is not necessarily the same as the value returned by recv().` What else could recv() return beside 0 or the number of bytes?

Comment: When sending data over TCP, the data stream is divided into packages (usually in the order of 1500 bytes). These packages arrive independently at the receiver, and as soon as one arrives (and if it's not out of order) it will be returned by `recv`. This means e.g. one call to `recv` could give you the first half and a later call the second half of your message. You have to make sure that you have reassembled your complete message before processing it, that's why one usually sends the length of the following data first.

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks for the explanation. So if I unsterstand that right, I need to take care of that if my message is longer than 1500 bytes or at least close to that lenght, but not, if it's significantly shorter (like 100 bytes or so)? Or is it still important to do so?

Comment: You could also have the opposite case where two short messages are in one package. So I don't dare to say that it will never be a problem if your messages are short. It probably will be ok, but you can't guarantee it.